# How to test Gin-gonic controller properly?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm learning golang by using Gin-gonic as http handler framework. I have a controller for an endpoint which makes operations with my own `Email` struct as following:

```golang
func EmailUserVerification(c *gin.Context) {
    var input validators.EmailUserVerificationValidator
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    email := models.Email{
        To:       input.To,
        Subject:  input.Subject,
        Template: "user_verification.html",
        TemplateData: notices.EmailUserVerificationTemplateData{
            Name:             input.Name,
            VerificationLink: input.VerificationLink,
        },
        Sender: models.NewEmailSMTPSender(input.From),
    }

    if err := email.Deliver(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, nil)
}
```

Struct `Email` is already test, nevertheless I do not know how to test this method properly. how it is supposed `Email` struct to be mocked here?

I registered the handler as gin-gonic documentation say:

```golang
router.POST("/emails/users/verify", controllers.EmailUserVerification)
```

Maybe could I inject an Email interface in the handler? if it is the case, how can I inject it?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can testing it by creating test file that have testing function inside it and mock other calling function.
For me I use testify/mock to mocking func (for further explanation, you should reading from other site first like medium and GitHub mock repo )

For example
If I have route path like this
`v1.POST("/operators/staffs", handler.CreateStaff)`
and have function `handler.CreateStaff` that inside call func `handler.OperatorStaffUseCase.CreateStaff`

I will create file create_staff_test.go that should look like this

```
package operator_staff

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
    jsoniter "github.com/json-iterator/go"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "onboarding-service/app/entities"
    staffUseCaseMock "onboarding-service/app/mocks/usecases"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestStaffHandler_CreateStaff(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        invitationId   = "3da465a6-be13-405e-a653-c68adf59f2be"
        firstName      = "Tom"
        lastName       = "Sudchai"
        roleId         = uint(1)
        roleName       = "role"
        operatorCode   = "velo"
        email          = "toms@gmail.com"
        password       = "P@ssw0rd"
        hashedPassword = "$2y$12$S0Gbs0Qm5rJGibfFBTARa.6ap9OBuXYbYJ.deCzsOo4uQNJR1KbJO"
    )

    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer ctrl.Finish()
    staffMock := staffUseCaseMock.NewMockOperatorStaffUseCase(ctrl)

    executeWithContext := func(mockUseCase *staffUseCaseMock.MockOperatorStaffUseCase, jsonRequestBody []byte, operatorCode string) *httptest.ResponseRecorder {
        response := httptest.NewRecorder()
        context, ginEngine := gin.CreateTestContext(response)

        requestUrl := "/v1/operators/staffs"
        httpRequest, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", requestUrl, strings.NewReader(string(jsonRequestBody)))

        NewEndpointHTTPHandler(ginEngine, mockUseCase)
        ginEngine.ServeHTTP(response, httpRequest)
        return response
    }

    createdStaffEntity := entities.OperatorStaff{
        ID:        roleId,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName:  lastName,
        Email:     email,
        Password:  hashedPassword,
        Operators: []entities.StaffOperator{{
            OperatorCode: operatorCode, RoleID: roleId,
        }},
    }

    t.Run("Happy", func(t *testing.T) {
        jsonRequestBody, _ := json.Marshal(createStaffFromInviteRequestJSON{
            InvitationId:    invitationId,
            FirstName:       firstName,
            LastName:        lastName,
            Password:        password,
            ConfirmPassword: password,
        })
    
        staffMock.EXPECT().CreateStaff(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).Return(&createdStaffEntity, nil)

        res := executeWithContext(staffMock, jsonRequestBody, operatorCode)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, res.Code)
    })
}
```

you will see
first mocking func when initially test
`staffMock := staffUseCaseMock.NewMockOperatorStaffUseCase(ctrl)`
and call in inside test case happy case

`staffMock.EXPECT().CreateStaff(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).Return(&createdStaffEntity, nil)`
that is mocking function that will return value as I want (again you should read more about gomock and you will understand what I trying to say)

or for easy way to learn about testing is fallow this tutorial
https://github.com/JacobSNGoodwin/memrizr